# Sybase AseCommand Execute SQL string

Tags: stored-procedures, ado.net, execute, dynamic-sql, sap-ase

I've found an interesting thing in Sybase AdoNet driver. I could not execute dynamics sql statements properly with it.

I have a very little stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE
    GetCustomerByName
    @customerFirstName nvarchar(50),
    @customerLastName nvarchar(50),
    @intParameter int AS
    /* Adaptive Server has expanded all '*' elements in the following statement */ 
    SELECT
        Customer.Id,
        Customer.FirstName,
        Customer.LastName
    FROM
        Customer
    WHERE
        FirstName = @customerFirstName
        AND LastName = @customerLastName
```

I would like to execute dynamic sql statements against this stored procedure:

```
using (var aseConnection = new AseConnection(SybaseConnectionString))
using (var aseCommand = aseConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    aseConnection.Open();

    aseCommand.CommandText = @"
        execute GetCustomerByName
            @customerFirstName = ?,
            @customerLastName = ?,
            @intParameter = 1";

    aseCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    aseCommand.Parameters.Add(0, "John");
    aseCommand.Parameters.Add(1, "Doe");

    using (var dataReader = aseCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "Id: {0} - First Name: {1} - Last Name: {2}",
                dataReader.GetInt32(0),
                dataReader.GetString(1),
                dataReader.GetString(2));
        }
    }
}
```

But unfortunately I get an exception:

```
Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Must declare variable '@dr_ta0'.

  Source=Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient
  StackTrace:
       at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand.CheckResult(Int32 res)
       at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand.Execute(CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
       at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand._ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior commandBehavior)
       at Sybase.Data.AseClient1.AseCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at Sybase.Data.AseClient.AseCommand.ExecuteReader()
       at AseCommandTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\jkanczler\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\AseCommandTest\AseCommandTest\Program.cs:line 61
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

As I see Sybase does not support very well the parameter passing to an AseCommand. What's the best practice then to execute dynamic sql statements with AseCommand?

Comment: Why do you want to execute stored procedure using dynamic sql?

Comment: Because we're using NHibernate but we have a legacy database with lot of stored procedures. We can't export all of the business logic from the SPs at once, so we have to live with it. Unfortunately the NHibernate executes SPs as dynamic SQL statements with different parameter ordering. So we have to map this parameters to the specific ones with named parameters.